# SMTP/POP3 on iPhone OS

Tags: iphone

I want to develop a mail client on iPhone, it's similar to mail.app available on iPhone.
I have tried to search on internet but not found how to send mail over SMTP and get mail over POP3 to my app.
Please help me !!

Comment: This question is far to broad. Consider refining your question into something more specific.

Answer (score 0):

SMTP is defined by [RFC 821](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0821.txt) and updated by [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321)

POP is defined by [RFC 1939](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1939.txt)

Answer (score 0):

The remail-iphone project might be a good start for you.

It used to be an app in the app store, but it went open source:

http://code.google.com/p/remail-iphone/